# Cannot resolve symbol PlayerView

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

Getting error:

> Cannot resolve symbol PlayerView

Trying to use `Exoplayer2`, and I'm supposed to attach it to a `PlayerView`. Problem is Android Studio is not able to find PlayerView anywhere.

My imports in the gradle file look like this.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:r2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:r2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:r2.4.0'
```

What's going on?

Comment: I changed to use `SimpleExoPlayerView`, seems to work so far...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SimpleExoPlayerView` is [deprecated](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ui/SimpleExoPlayerView.html) and recommends that `PlayerView` is used instead.

It is part of `exoplayer-ui` package and can be included through gradle available in `v2.8.2`.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.8.2' // This includes PlayerView
```